# How to append an element in the end of list structure in java?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, append

I'm trying to write a function to append a new element in the end of my list. But i dont know how my method always append new element in the first index of the list.

I have 2 class named Waypoint and TourElement. Waypoint contains method to handle points in linked list. TourElment contains waypoint and next.

Waypoint.java

```
public class Waypoint {
    int x  ;
    int y  ;
    public int getX()
    {
        return this.x;
    }
    public int getY()
    {
        return this.y;
    }
    public void setXY(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

TourElement.java

```
 public class TourElement {
     private Waypoint points;
     private TourElement next;
     public void setWaypoint( Waypoint points)
     {
         this.points = points; 
     }
     public void setTourElement(TourElement next)
     {
         this.next = next;
     }
     Waypoint getWaypoint()
     {
         return this.points;
     }

     TourElement getNext()
     {
         return this.next;
     }

     //+ method below
}
```

method add new TourElement in the list, Why is alway append TourElement in the first index of the list?

```
public TourElement append(Waypoint waypoint)
{
    TourElement newTourElement = new TourElement();
    TourElement current = this;
    while(current.next != null)
    {
        current = current.next;
    }
    newTourElement.setWaypoint(waypoint);
    current.next = newTourElement;
    return newTourElement;
}
```

Here is my test case:
//create an element list:

```
private TourElement createElementList(int[][] waypoints){
        assert waypoints.length > 0;
        TourElement elem = new TourElement();
        int lastIndex = waypoints.length-1;
        Waypoint wp = createWaypoint(waypoints[lastIndex][0], waypoints[lastIndex][1]);
        elem.setWaypoint(wp);
        for (int i = lastIndex-1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
            wp = createWaypoint(waypoints[i][0], waypoints[i][1]);
            elem = elem.addStart(wp);
        }
        return elem;
    }
```

//create an waypoint:

```
private Waypoint createWaypoint(int x, int y) {
        Waypoint wp = new Waypoint();
        wp.setXY(x, y);
        return wp;
    }
```

//add Start

```
public   TourElement addStart(Waypoint wp) {
     TourElement newTourElement = new TourElement();
     newTourElement.setWaypoint(wp);
     newTourElement.setTourElement(this);
     return newTourElement;   
    }  



 public void testAppend() {
        TourElement elem = createElementList(new int[][] {{2, 2}});
        elem = elem.append(createWaypoint(3, 3));
        assertArrayEquals(new int[] {2, 2}, elem.getWaypoint().toArray());
        assertArrayEquals(new int[] {3, 3}, elem.getNext().getWaypoint().toArray());
        assertNull(elem.getNext().getNext());
    }

public void testAppend_AfterTwo() {
    TourElement elem = createElementList(new int[][] {{1, 1}, {2, 2}});
    elem = elem.append(createWaypoint(3, 3));
    assertArrayEquals(new int[] {1, 1}, elem.getWaypoint().toArray());
    assertArrayEquals(new int[] {2, 2}, elem.getNext().getWaypoint().toArray());
    assertArrayEquals(new int[] {3, 3}, elem.getNext().getNext().getWaypoint().toArray());
    assertNull(elem.getNext().getNext().getNext());
}
```

I expect that the output will look like this:

**Test case 1**: {2,2} => {3,3}

**Test case 2**:  {1,1} => {2,2} =>{3,3}

But my actual output is:

**Test case 1**: {3, 3} => {2,2}

**Test case 2**:  {3,3} =>{1,1} =>{2,2}

Comment: What does `createElementList` do?

Comment: As @Jonk asked, explain `createWaypoint` and `createElementList` methods, please

Comment: I'm sorry, I just editted my code. createElementList will create an ElementList including a lot of point. Waypoint create a point look like that: (1,2).

Answer (score 0):

You're updating your "`elem`" in the line `elem = elem.append(createWaypoint(3, 3));`.

So I wonder, how your test cases return the complete list anyway? I'd expect the "actual output" would be "`{3,3}`" only.

To solve the issue, the test should NOT change the `elem` variable at all, after it's initialized in first place:

```
 public void testAppend() {
        // add "final" to prevent accidentially changes of references
        final TourElement elem = createElementList(new int[][] {{2, 2}});

        // DO NOT CHANGE "elem"!
        // elem = elem.append(createWaypoint(3, 3));
        // instead keep the reference to the first elem:
        elem.append(createWaypoint(3, 3));

        assertArrayEquals(new int[] {2, 2}, elem.getWaypoint().toArray());
        assertArrayEquals(new int[] {3, 3}, elem.getNext().getWaypoint().toArray());
        assertNull(elem.getNext().getNext());
    }
```

BTW: your code could be MUCH clearer, if you give the "`Waypoint`" a constructor "`Waypoint(x, y)`", make the `x` and `y` fields final, remove `setXY()` and add a `toString()`.

```
public class Waypoint {
    final int x;
    final int y;
    public WayPoint(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int getX() { ... }
    public int getY() { ... }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("{%d,%d}", x, y);
    }
}
```

Your `TourElement` could need a `Collection<Waypoint> waypoints()` method, which returns subsequent `Waypoint` objects (makes testing easier).

```
public Collection<Waypoint> waypoints() {
    Collection<Waypoint> res = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
    TourElement currTE = this;
    while (currTE.next()!=null) {
        res.add(currTE.getWaypoint());
        currTE = currTE.next();
    }
    return res;
}
```

To then print the list of `Waypoint`, you simply do

```
    org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join(elem.waypoints(), ", ");
```

Comment: i see, the test case is provided by my teacher, so I don't know that. But when do not change elem, the test case does not run.  I got an error "null PointerException". what does that mean?

Comment: can you review my append() method? I think that my code is wrong in this method...

Comment: Well, I removed the `elem = ` and the test ran without problems... code: https://pastebin.com/z6w26ikw

Comment: i dont knoww, but the test did'nt run when I was trying to removed the elem.. I don't know why. I use netbean for my homework.... It got an error "null PointerException". and because the test case is provided by our professor, so I  don't know what I'm doing run\

Comment: Ok. Since the test case is provided, you could try to not to change the "`elem`" reference by just returning the "`elem`" again. That could be performed by returning "`elem`" in `append()`. `elem` there is the same as `this`. Try to replace the last line of `append()` with `return this;`.